# Proofs with Quotient-Remainder theorem

Tags: combinatorics

This is a question, that requires quotient-remainder theorem to solve.

If $m, n$, and $d \in \mathbb{Z}$, $d>0$, and $d|(m-n)$, what is the relation between $m \mod {d}$ and $n \mod {d}$? Prove your answer.

Comment: By quotient remainder theorem, m-n=kd + r for some integers k and r, and 0<=r<d.

Comment: However, since d|m-n, then r = 0, and m-n = kd

Comment: I am stuck here now. Can I get some help. How to prove that both m and n are divisible by k?

Comment: You can't prove $m$ and $n$ are divisible by $k$ --- there is no reason why they should be. What you can try to do is prove that $m\mod d$ and $n\mod d$ are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to consider carefully the information you are given. You want to find the relationship between $m \mod d$ and $n \mod d$. Let's use the quotient-remainder theorem first to understand those expressions better:

$m=q_1d+r_1$

$n=q_2d+r_2$

Where $0\le r_1, r_2 \lt d$ are the least non-negative residues of $m, n \mod d$.

The other piece of information you are given concerns $m-n$. Can you see how to combine what you know (including the sizes of $r_1, r_2$) to reach a conclusion?

Comment: ok. however, but I don't understand why you can make the assumption that m and n are as what you stated above, and not like 'reverse engineer' or derive m and n from m-n = kd?

Comment: @Trialx - I have just divided $m$ and $n$ by $d$ to get the quotient and remainder in each case - the form is quite general. Given any number I can find $q$ and $r$ which work. That's what I thought you meant by the quotient-remainder theorem. If you mean something else, you could state it.

Comment: @Trialx Do you know the result - the answer you want to get to? If you do it is easy to go either way. But you seem to have confused yourself a bit in the comments by bringing in $k$ and the idea of divisibility by $k$. This approach picks out $r_1$ and $r_2$ explicitly.

Comment: ok. I think I got what you meant in your subsequent question. Thanks